# Simple Mysql Select Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need help building a mysql query. 
I have a table like this

```
----------|-------------
user_name | blood_group
----------|------------
Alex      | O+
Jhon      | A+
Rob       | AB-
Jenny     | O+
Suzanne   | O+
-----------------------
```

I want to select all blood groups but only for O+ blood group I want to check if the username is Alex or not. If the username is Alex for O+, I will select that otherwise not.

So the query will return me:

```
----------|-------------
user_name | blood_group
----------|------------
Alex      | O+
Jhon      | A+
Rob       | AB-
-----------------------
```

Comment: Sounds good. Have fun. Seriously though, what's the question?

Comment: @PatrickQ:- Read carefully:- `I want to select all blood groups but only for O+ blood group I want to check if the username is Alex or not. If the username is Alex for O+, I will select that otherwise not.`

Comment: @R.T. That's not a question.

Comment: Where's the *"here's what I tried, but it failed"* part?

Comment: @PatrickQ:- I think that is the question however OP has certainly missed to show his effort!

Comment: *"I need help building..."* - You need to read the tutorials; and to answer your question: use a [`WHERE`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-where/) clause. You won't learn anything from "given" answers. Have you not tried something; *anything?* - Questions not showing any code that you've tried and effort you've put into it, tend to get a bad review.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was making a query to show search results based on user inputs and wanted to show only Alex for O+ blood group. But I got confused on this part and could not find a solution. Thats why I posted it.

I tried with "LEFT JOIN" and ".... WHERE `blood_group` OR (`blood_group` = 'O+' AND `user_name` = 'Alex')"

Comment: @EnnFenn I understand. I suggest that you put information like that (as you said) in your question or any other future questions you may have. In doing that, this will tell people *"Oh ok, he/she tried this but is having problems with it".* - Not doing so, some may think that it's asking to write code. I'm just trying to help you out and write better questions. :)

Comment: ...the tried code (in your comment) should have been part of your question. That will help people a lot, including you ;)

Comment: You're very much welcome Enn, *cheers*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will select all rows which have user = 'Alex' and blood_group = 'O+' and all rows which don't have blood_group = 'O+':

```
SELECT user_name, blood_group
FROM myTable
WHERE (blood_group = 'O+' AND user_name = 'Alex')
OR blood_group != 'O+'
```

Comment: generally you should select the specific rows you want to use. i would recommend you change * to user_name , blood_group

Comment: You are right, I wrote the query on top of my head focusing more on the conditions.

Answer (score 4):

This will work for you

```
select user_name,blood_group
from bloodtable
where  blood_group <> 'O+' 
or (blood_group = 'O+' and user_name = 'Alex' )
```

Comment: @John Ruddell thanks for edditing

Comment: @Parando of course :) we knew what you meant.. typos are typos

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
select user_name , blood_group from table_name
where (blood_group='O+' and user_name='Alex')
or blood_group !='O+' ;
```

Comment: How is this any different from the two answers that were already posted?

Answer (score 1):

A simplification of the other answers.

```
SELECT user_name, blood_group
  FROM myTable
 WHERE user_name = 'Alex' 
    OR blood_group != 'O+';
```

Comment: What if there's an Alex with a different blood group?

Comment: @EndeNeu This is the exact same logic as your answer.

Comment: Sorry my bad, you are right.